# How can I match a word containing every vowel at least once?

Tags: regex

How can I match a word containing every vowel at least once?

Comment: I think he looks for words like "abstemious", that contain all vowels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this

```
\s* (?= \S* a)  (?= \S* e)  (?= \S* i)  (?= \S* o)  (?= \S* u)  (?= \S* y) (\S*)
```

Answer (score 4):

It depends what you mean by a “vowel” — and for that matter, what you mean by “word”, too — but the normal way would be something like this:

```
(?xsi)
(?= .* a)
(?= .* e)
(?= .* i)
(?= .* o)
(?= .* u)
(?= .* y)
```

But you don’t want to do it that way.  You want to put the logical conjunction in the programming language proper, not the regex, which leads to something like this (disregarding casing issues):

```
/a/ && /e/ && /i/ && /o/ && /u/ && /y/
```

## What’s a Vowel?

Note that the entire “vowel” issue is pretty ridiculous, because any continuant can act like a vowel, even if it doesn’t look like one. That means that some letters that don’t look like vowels, are. Plus sometimes letters look like vowels but aren’t.

1. For example, the *s* is *psst*, the second *l* in *little*, the *r* in *acre*, and the *n* in *nth* are all acting as vowels. Plus there’s the famous word *cwm*, from Welsh, where *w* is a vowel.
2. Furthermore, the *e* in *Mike* is not acting as a vowel, whereas the *i* there is a diphthong (two vowels fused).
3. Also, while the *y* in *sky* is a vowel, the *y* in *yellow* is not a vowel.
4. You’ll have to figure out how many vowels you think there are in words like *lie* or *speak*, or even *queue*.
5. Finally, if you have diacritics, you have to decide whether to count them as separate.  Are *e*, *é*, *è*, and *ê* just one vowel, or four?

Comment: I know it shouldn't be done with a regex, but I'm just curious. I can't get your first example working though ;o

Comment: @JohnConnor Then run the first solution all together without spaces. You probably don’t have `/x` working.

Comment: @tchrist What is `(?xsi)`?  (JS complains it's not a valid group, fwiw.)

Comment: @broofa - Kindof shocking. I guess you could test it. Have you tired the individual characters? ie; `(?x)`,`(?s)`,`(?i)` ? Any of those types supported?

Comment: To answer my own question: See the 'modifiers' section of http://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html.  @sin: Looks like JS (at least in Chrome) doesn't support modifier groups.

Comment: @broofa - Does it support the `/../mod` syntax?